# Any good tool to convert HTML entities in HTML documents to plain UTF characters?

Tags: html, windows, xhtml

I have many HTML documents containing many HTML entities of Unicode code point representation, e.g. `&#1576;&#1585;&#1608;&#1581;`

Is there a good tool to convert HTML entities in multiple HTML documents to plain UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32 characters?

I want an offline converter tool that can do a batch job for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool, but it doesn't seem like it would be hard to write one.

Comment: What is it that you want to do really? Do you only want to convert the HTML entities into plain characters, or do you also want to convert the documents from UTF-8 to UTF-16 or UTF-32?

Comment: Yes, but I'm so lazy except really theres is no such a tool.

Comment: @Guffa, yup, I only want to convert the HTML entities into plain characters. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU utility "recode" will do this, with the invocation

> recode HTML..UTF-16LE < old.html > new.html

(or UTF-16BE, of course.)

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/recode/recode-3.6.tar.gz

It's use of HTML as a character set is a bit of a hack and is treated as either ASCII or LATIN-1, when it should be treated as a "surface" for any character set.  If there are any UTF-8 characters, it can break, so I'm now withdrawing my recommendation.  Use the first.

(You might expect `recode UTF-8..HTML,HTML..UTF-16LE` to work, but this first encodes the ampersands...)

Comment: Will it just convert the encoding, or can also convert HTML entities to their plain characters?

Comment: @Vantomex: This converts both the text _and_ the HTML entities to UTF16.  It defined this HTML pseudo-character-set specifically to handle HTML entities.  Everything besides the entities is handled as  ASCII.

Comment: @Vantomex: Did you want to convert the files to UTF-16 also, not just convert the HTML entities? That's not what you answered in your comment...

Comment: @Gufa, I didn't demand X encoding to UTF-16 conversion because I can do it easily using **HTML Tidy** or **UTFCast**. Actually your answer had already satisfied me, I would accept both answer if I could but unfortunately I couldn't, I vote up yours though :-). However, since my question is about a *tool*, I think @wnoise answer was more relevant.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of such a tool, but you could easily write one. This C# code for example would convert all html files in the current folder:

```
foreach (string name in Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.html")) {
  string s = File.ReadAllText(name);
  s = Regex.Replace(
    s,
    @"&#(\d+);",
    m => ((char)Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value)).ToString()
  );
  File.WriteAllText(name, s);
}
```

Comment: Oops, I missed regex could be used for this purpose. For simplicity, I will use PowerGREP instead. Thanks @Guffa.

Comment: Well, after more thinking, I realize that there is no decimal Unicode representation in regex. So, I'll go into your direction.